# How to print occurrences of numbers in Scala?

Tags: list, scala, count, distinct-values, find-occurrences

I am new to Scala. 
Kindly help me with the expected output

```
    val list =List(1,123,2,3,123,1,2) 
    val result = aList.map(x => aList.count(_==x)))
    println(result.distinct)
```

Expected Output: Number of occurrence of 1 is 2
                 Number of occurrence of 2 is 2
                 Number of occurrence of 123 is 2
                 Number of occurrence of 3 is 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`groupBy` works well for this. It returns a `Map` of elements grouped by a discriminator function which in the case is the element itself also known as `identity`

`scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[Int]] = HashMap(1 -> List(1, 1), 2 -> List(2, 2), 3 -> List(3), 123 -> List(123, 123))`

Which we can work from.
Then map each key/value pair to a key and the `size` of the values `List` which gives what you are looking for.

```
list.groupBy(identity).map({case(k,v) => (k, v.size)})
scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = HashMap(1 -> 2, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 1, 123 -> 2)
```

With Scala 2.13 we can use `groupMapReduce` as LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez notes.

`list.groupMapReduce(identity)(_ => 1)(_ + _)`

Similar to the approach above, the first parameter is given the `identity` function to group the values, the second parameter maps each value to `1`, and the third is given a function `_ + _` to add them together.

This gives a similar answer as the original approach:
`scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 2, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 1, 123 -> 2)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Number of occurrence of 1 is 2                                                                      
Number of occurrence of 2 is 2                                                                      Number of occurrence of 123 is 2                                                               
   Number of occurrence of 3 is 1

Comment: @SoumyaPillai that is a different question. You need to iterate the map and print the results, it shouldn't be that hard, think about how would you print each entry.  - Brian, it may be good to tell that in **2.13** you can do the same with `groupMapReduce`.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thanks for that. I've seen that before but have not kept up with **2.13** much. Here's what I came up with: `list.groupMapReduce(identity)(_ => 1)(_ + _)`

Comment: @Brian , @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez  Thanks for your help.   I got the expected results.                                                       
    ```list.groupBy(identity).map({case(k,v)=> (k,v.size)}).foreach(x => 
    println("Number of occurances of " + x._1 + " is : " + x._2))  ```                                                        
    ```list.groupMapReduce(identity)(_ => 1)(_ + _).foreach(x => println("Number of 
    occurancces of " + x._1 + " is :" + x._2)) ```